# Sequelize.js - column from junction table in "where" clause

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a project in [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) as ORM.

I've created a Many-to-Many relationship and I need to make a query using some columns from the junction table in "where" clause.

I have the following models:

```
sequelize.define("User", {
    //some values
}, {
    "classMethods" : {
        "associate" : function (models) {
            User.hasMany(models.Book, { "through" : models.BorrowedBook });
        }
    }
});

sequelize.define("Book", {
    //some values
}, {
    "classMethods" : {
        "associate" : function (models) {
            Book.hasMany(models.User, { "through" : models.BorrowedBook });
        }
    }
});

sequelize.define("BorrowedBook", {
        //some other values
        "returnedAt" : DataTypes.DATE
    }
);
```

How can I use in "where" clause a column from "BorrowedBook"?

E.g. I want to get all users with books eagerly loaded that have at least 1 book and "BorrowedBook.returnedAt" is null.

Is there a way, something like this ?

```
db.Book
    .find({
        "include" : [
            db.User,
            { "model" : db.BorrowedBook, "where" : { "borrowedAt" : null } }
        ]
    })
```

Comment: If you use the master branch of sequelize you should be able to do something like `{model: db.User, through: { where: { borrowedAt: null } } }`

Answer (score 2):

You can't include the through model like that unless you have actually setup relations to the through model directly, but you still won't accomplish what you want.

The latest master of Sequelize should support something like:

```
db.Book.find({
  include: [
    {model: db.User, through: {
      where: {borrowedAt: null}
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: I could not make it work, I've tried with v1.7.5 and v2.0.0.dev11 and none of them worked. The "through" index has no effect.

Comment: Ah then it wasn't covered by the attributes implementation. Open a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: I've opened a feature requests. For any other people interested here is the link: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1775